# Laravel get uploaded image on CKEDITOR

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ckeditor

when i use from `ckeditor` to upload image and attach that on post my upload image function in controller work fine without any problem, but when i want to return uploaded image to that, ckeditor can't get that, for example this is my code:

Controller:

```
public function uploadImageContent()
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'upload' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,gif,png'
    ]);

    $file = request()->file('upload');
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    $year = Carbon::now()->year;
    $imagePath = "/uploads/post_images/{$year}/";

    if (file_exists(public_path($imagePath) . $filename)) {
        $filename = Carbon::now()->timestamp . '.' . $filename;
    }

    $file->move(public_path() . $imagePath, $filename);

    $url = $imagePath . $filename;

    return "<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(1,'{$url}','')</script>";
}
```

this function work fine and i dont get any error on `console` or `network`

```
return "<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(1,'{$url}','')</script>";
```

should be return path, but dont work.

view:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        CKEDITOR.replace('description', {
            height: '200px',
            extraPlugins: 'forms',
            filebrowserUploadUrl:'/dashboard/administrator/attachImage',
            filebrowserImageUploadUrl:'/dashboard/administrator/attachImage'
        });

    });
</script>
```

route:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Dashboard', 'prefix' => 'dashboard'], function () {
    $this->group(['prefix' => 'administrator'], function () {
        ...
        $this->post('/attachImage', 'ContentsController@attachImage');
        ...
});
```

ContentsController:

```
class ContentsController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function attachImage()
    {
        $this->uploadImageContent(request()->all());
    }
}
```

Comment: That is only string containing `script` html tag. Javascript doesn't aware that it's should be appended to DOM, unless you told to.

Comment: @Chay22 like with this implementation is work fine in my other project

Comment: you should take a look at [`getFileCallback`](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-CKEditor#update-the-elfinder-page-being-called-by-ckeditor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `echo` instead of `return` resolve my problem:

```
echo "<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(1,'{$url}','')</script>";
```

i have this issue on `laravel 5.5`

Comment: You should also use the 'return' statement in "attachImage" method, because in the "uploadImageContent" method, you only return the result to the callback function and not the client.

Answer (score 3):

Your code did not work for me. What I observed is, you are not embedding the `CKEditorFuncNum` (which server receives as POST variable) at the place of `1` as the first parameter to `callFunction()`. I replaced the `1` with `$request->CKEditorFuncNum` and then I used `return` statement instead of `echo` and it all works.

**Here's your code:**
`echo "<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(1,'{$url}','')</script>";`

and

**Here's my code:**
`return  "<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction('{$request->CKEditorFuncNum}','{$url}','')</script>";`

**I'm on Laravel 5.8**

Hope it helps others.